# how to delete entire row in csv file and save changes on same file?

Tags: python, csv

i'm new with python and try to modify csv file so i will able to delete specific rows with specific fields according to given list.
in my current code i get the rows which i want to delete but i can't delete it and save the changes on same file (replace).

```
 import os, sys, glob
 import time ,csv
 # Open a file
 path = 'C:\\Users\\tzahi.k\\Desktop\\netzer\\'
 dirs = os.listdir( path )
 fileslst = []
 alertsCode = ("42001", "42003", "42006","51001" , "51002" ,"61001" ,"61002","71001",
          "71002","71003","71004","71005","71006","72001","72002","72003","72004",
          "82001","82002","82003","82004","82005","82006","82007","83001","84001")
 # This would print the unnesscery codes 
 for file in dirs:
    if "ALERTS" in file.upper()  :
       fileslst.append(file)
fileslst.sort()

with open(fileslst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvReader:
         for alert in alertsCode:
             if any(alert in row[2] for s in alertsCode) :
             print row
```

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read all the rows into a list using a *list comprehension* and excluding the unwanted rows. Then *rewrite* the rows to the file in mode `w` (write mode) which overwrites or replaces the content of the file:

```
with open(fileslst[-1], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    clean_rows = [row for row in csvReader if not any(alert in row[2] for alert in alertsCode)]
    # csvfile.truncate()

with open(fileslst[-1], 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerows(clean_rows)
```

Comment: is there a reason for the reading and writing in binary (`'rb'`, `'wb'`) mode?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis No reason in particular. Only following OP's precedence

Comment: @TzahiKadosh "You are appreciate it" would return a `TypeError`. Nerdy joke alert.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the reason for using binary mode is that it's what the documentation says : " If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).