# How to delete rows from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I was able to pull the rows that I would like to delete from a CSV file but I can't make that `drop()` function to work.

```
data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
data_top = data.head()
data_top = data_top.drop(axis=0)
```

What needs to be added?

Example of a CSV file. It should delete everything until it reaches the Employee column.

```
creation date         Unnamed: 1       Unnamed: 2
0            NaN   type of client         NaN
1            age             NaN          NaN
2            NaN      birth date          NaN
3            NaN             NaN       days off
4       Employee          Salary       External
5            Dan            130e          yes
6        Abraham             10e           no
7       Richmond            201e      third-party
```

Comment: Do you want to remove rows from the dataframe or in the csv file you made the dataframe from?

Comment: The purpose is to remove rows from the CSV file. But if I can drop those rows from the data frame, I know how to "transfer" the information from the data frame to the CSV file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769041/how-to-delete-entire-row-in-csv-file-and-save-changes-on-same-file)

Comment: Ok. So judging from the code, what you want to do is read in the CSV file as a dataframe, and delete the top 5 rows from it and store it back to the CSV?

Comment: You are right!!

Comment: ok in that case you can do it in the way I provided below.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the top 5 rows you want to delete, then you can do it as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
data.drop([0,1,2,3,4], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

With axis, you should also pass either a single label or list (of column names, or row indexes).

There are, of course, many other ways to achieve this too. Especially if the case is that the index of rows you want to delete is not just the top 5.

**edit:** inplace added as pointed out in comments.

Comment: You may also use 'inplace' = True inside the drop method, so you don't have create the variable again

Comment: Actually, is quite complex what I'm trying to achieve. (at least for a beginner like myself). I'm trying to delete all the rows and the columns from a CSV file until it reaches a column named "Employees". So I had luck that this head() function with no argument matched my current file format - because now it contains 5 rows until "employees" cell, but this will not be the case in the future.

Comment: @zimskiz For this particular use case this code snippet will work then.

Comment: Can you please show the first lines of your dataframe. The read_csv method is quite flexible, you can read specific columns if you want.

Comment: The initial question was updated with an example. The skiprows is not a good choice as the number of rows can be different from a file to another.

Comment: Probably best to open a new question for this since the nature of what you're asking totally changes with the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the coments and further explanations, assuming you know the name of the column, and that you have a positional index, you can try the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
row = data[data['creation date'] == 'Employee']
n = row.index[0]
data.drop(labels=list(range(n)), inplace=True)
```

The main goal is to find the index of the row that contains the value 'Employee'. To achieve that, assuming there are no other rows that contain that word, you can filter the dataframe to match the value in question in the specific column.

 
After that, you extract the index value, wich you will use to create a list of labels (given a positional index) that you will drop of the dataframe, as @MAK7 stated in his answer.